# Fitting points to a wrapped line

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I have a set of points that is wrapped between -360 and 360 degrees. I am currently trying to fit a line through them without unwrapping the dataset. Is there a way to either alter scikit's LinearRegression model? Otherwise what's the best way of writing a line fitting algorithm that would account for the wrap in the data's model?

[image]

Comment: What is the problem w/ unwrapping the data?

Comment: @ScottHunter might simply not work if there is too nuch noise.

Comment: If you can't unwrap it due to noise, doesn't bode well for line fitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At interesting noise levels maybe brute force cannot be avoided.

Here are the squared errors (using wrap-around distance) as a function of the slope (best intercept is chosen at each point) for three models with noise levels 90, 180, 180 and 64, 96, 128 data points (cf. script below).

[image]

I'm not sure there is a smart way of reliably finding the global minima of those.

OTOH, brute force works reasonably well even in cases that look rather difficult, like the bottom one. Dashed line is true model without noise, dots are actual data generated by adding noise to true model, solid line is reconstruction.

[image]

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as so
from operator import attrgetter
from matplotlib import pylab

def setup(interc, slope, sigma, N):
    x = np.random.uniform(0.1, 2.0, (N,)).cumsum()
    y = (interc + x*slope + np.random.normal(0, sigma, (N,)) + 360) % 720 - 360
    return x, y

def err_model_full(params, x, y):
    interc, slope = params
    err = (interc + x*slope - y + 360) % 720 - 360
    return np.dot(err, err)

def err_model(interc, slope, x, y):
    err = (interc + x*slope - y + 360) % 720 - 360
    return np.dot(err, err)

for i, (interc, slope, sigma, N) in enumerate([(100, -12, 90, 64),
                                               (-30, 20, 180, 96),
                                               (66, -49, 180, 128)]):

    # create problem
    x, y = setup(interc, slope, sigma, N)

    # brute force through slopes
    slps = np.linspace(-128, 128, 257)
    ics, err = zip(*map(attrgetter('x', 'fun'), (so.minimize(err_model, (0,), args = (sl, x, y)) for sl in slps)))
    best = np.argmin(err)
    # polish
    res = so.minimize(err_model_full, (ics[best], slps[best]), args = (x, y))

    # plot

    pylab.figure(1)
    pylab.subplot(3, 1, i+1)
    pylab.plot(slps, err)
    pylab.figure(2)
    pylab.subplot(3, 1, i+1)
    pylab.plot(x, y, 'o')
    ic_rec, sl_rec = res.x
    pylab.plot(x, (ic_rec + x*sl_rec + 360) % 720 - 360)
    pylab.plot(x, (interc + x*slope + 360) % 720 - 360, '--')

    print('true (intercept, slope)', (interc, slope), 'reconstructed',
          tuple(res.x))
    print('noise level', sigma)
    print('squared error for true params', err_model_full((interc, slope), x, y))
    print('squared error for reconstructed params', err_model_full(res.x, x, y))
pylab.figure(1)
pylab.savefig('bf.png')
pylab.figure(2)
pylab.savefig('recon.png')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is quite an interesting problem, because you've only got one feature as input that contains no information about the wrapping. The simplest way that comes to mind is just to use a nearest neighbours approach

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
import numpy as np

####################
# Create some data
n_points = 100
X = np.linspace(0, 1, n_points) - 0.3
y = (X*720*2 % 720) - 360
y = y + np.random.normal(0, 15, n_points)
X = X.reshape(-1, 1)
#######################

knn = KNeighborsRegressor()
knn.fit(X, y)

lspace = np.linspace(0, 1, 1000) - 0.3
lspace = lspace.reshape(-1, 1)
plt.scatter(X, y)
plt.plot(lspace, svr.predict(lspace), color='C1')
```

[image: KNN example]

However if you need it to be piecewise linear then I suggest you look at [this blog post](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/engineering/piecewise-regression/)

Comment: Just curious, what type of other information would give more information about the wrapping besides knowing that it wraps after 360 degrees?